# Extracting attribute with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php

I'm trying to extract the href attribute of link as a string.

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank" class="someclass">Read More</a>
```

I'm using the following to read the extract the attribute:

```
$link = simplexml_load_string($ad['meta_value']);
$order['logo'] = $logo['href']->asXML();
```

Instead of getting `http://example.com` I'm getting `href="http://example.com"`. Beside using str_replace() is there a way to extract the attribute as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat `@attributes` as object and convert to string:

```
$link = simplexml_load_string($ad['meta_value']);
echo (string) $link->attributes()->href;
```